# Posting http form-data request isn't working but showing 200ms status on Postman

Tags: node.js, json, express, mongoose, postman

I am having trouble while posting form data.
raw method and xxx-URL also works but in the case of sending form-data post request
I receive an error on console
The error looks like this
(node:12820) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ValidationError: login validation failed: email: Path 'email' is required., password: Path 'password' is required.
at model.Document.invalidate

```
//hers' the headers
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extend: true }));
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

// here's the function to post requests

function registration() {
  app.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
    const model = new Model({
      email: req.body.email,
      password: req.body.password,
    });
    res.send('posted');
    const result = await model.save();
    console.log(result);
  });
}

//here's the mongo portion


const port = process.env.port || 3000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`listening to port ${port}`));

mongoose
  .connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/Login', {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  .then(() => console.log('connected mfs'))
  .catch((err) => console.error('error found...', err));

const LoginSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: { type: String, required: true },
  password: { type: String, required: true },
});

const Model = mongoose.model('login', LoginSchema);
```

Comment: Are you sending your request in Postman?

Comment: yeah. your little help can save me days

Comment: Have you included `Content-type: application/json` in headers?

Comment: I have mentioned all the headers I used. 
`app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extend: true }));`

Comment: I meant have you included the `Content-type` inside header in Postman?

Comment: no, I haven't. actually, I didn't even touch it.
I just stay on body > form-data.
URL-encoded and RAW are working fine but not form-data.

Comment: Okay. So try sending your `email` and `password` inside `body > raw > json` and inside your `headers`, add `content-type` `application/json`.

Comment: well, as i mentioned earlier. 
every post method is working except you post data through `form-data`.
i have also tried your method of adding `content-type` and it worked too but it doesn't work on `FORM-DATA`

Comment: But why are you sending it as `form-data`? It wont work. Your code is expected to send requests' `body` as `json` or `url-encoded`.

Comment: I was just testing different methods to `POST data`